# javascript amateur problem offset().top jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a page on wordpress and want to add animation to my posts. Specifically, it is about leaving posts on the left and right when you scroll down on them. I have this code, but the smallest scroll motion causes it to turn on immediately.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  const windowHeight = $(window).height();
  const scrollValue = $(this).scrollTop();

  const $art2 = $("#post-134");
  const art2FromTop = $art2.offSet().top;
  const art2Height = $art2.outerHeight();

  if (scrollValue > art2FromTop + art2Height - windowHeight) {
    console.log("It works")
  }
})
```

Comment: It's `offset`, not `offSet`. JS is case sensitive

Comment: It's better if the title reflect the problem specifically

Comment: it didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: What does `console.log($art2.length);` output?

Comment: returns a number - 1